# Reporting Services: Multi-page Report - Show Page subtotal

Tags: reporting-services

I was assigned to evaluate if the `RS` (`Reporting Services`) are adequate to our application and I was given a list of requisites.

One of them is:

Assuming:

1. Having a table containing lines products and their prices
2. Being this table long and would span across multiple pages

I need to be able to show the sum of the prices of the products up to each page.

I've been meddling with `RS` since yesterday and I can't seem to find anything that permits me to do this. I've googled it a number of times and I can't find anything.

Any help would be appreciated. Tks.

Answer (score 1):

Add a footer to your page and a textbox

The textbox value should be **=SUM(ReportItems!price.value)**

The textbox display only the current page total.